# Modifying BootStrap4 Css for tooltip in angular2

Tags: html, css, angular, sass, ng-bootstrap

i have created ngbtooltip in my project , basically i am trying to override bootstrap 4 css when displaying the padding, colors and alignment.

I am trying to use a seperate css file so that i wont need to modify the master bootstrap css.

My html file is

```
<div class = 'test123' *ngIf = "config.description" >
<i [ngClass]="_tooltipClass" [placement]="_placement"  [ngbTooltip]="config.description"></i>
</div>
```

my css file that i created doesnt take any affect ,instead my tooltip is keep relying on the master css rather to listen to the css that i have created for the tooltip.

For an example , the master css file for bootstrap is using " text-align : center " whereby what am i trying to achieve is as stated below ,"text-align:right". but when i run my browser . it display the text to be center than react

```
.test123 .tooltip-inner  {
 max-width: $tooltip-max-width;
 padding: $tooltip-padding-y $tooltip-padding-x;
 color: $tooltip-color;
 text-align: right;**
 background-color: $tooltip-bg;
 @include border-radius($border-radius);

 &::before {
 position: absolute;
 width: 0; 
 height: 0;
 border-color: transparent;
 border-style: solid;
  }
}
```